# c# Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to System.Window.Forms.Textbox

Tags: c#

I have this error code "Cannot implicitly convert type 'double' to System.Window.Forms.Textbox" and i'm not sure why i'm getting it. If some one could exlpain it it would be great and give me ideas on how to fix it please. I have looked at other post but still can not work it out.

Thank you for your help

```
int SumOfSquares(int txtSide1, int txtSide2)
    {
        txtSide1 *= txtSide1;
        txtSide2 *= txtSide2;
        return txtSide1 + txtSide2;
    }

    private void btnCalculate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int Side1 = int.Parse(txtSide1.Text);
        int Side2 = int.Parse(txtSide2.Text);

        int SumLessOne = SumOfSquares(Side1, Side2) - 1;

        if (SumOfSquares(Side1, Side2) > 50)
        {
            txtHypotenuse.Text = "Overflow";
        }
        else
        {
            txtHypotenuse.Text = "Safe";
        }
        txtHypotenuse.Text = Math.Sqrt(SumOfSquares(Side1 , Side2)); // this is the line the error is on 

    }
}
```

Comment: Note: The OP code does not match the error message...

Comment: OP - Have you tried googling your error?

Comment: @Bharadwaj OP code is trying to assign a double to a string, but the quoted error message indicates that the code is trying to assign a double to a TextBox.

Comment: The code of your SumOfSquares is really a no-no. Why on earth you named the two local variables with the same name of two textboxes?

Comment: @MatthewWatson yes, I saw that now, carefully ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
txtHypotenuse.Text = Convert.ToString(Math.Sqrt(SumOfSquares(Side1 , Side2)));
```

Comment: Thanks for everones help yes i did google it a few times but could not find the right answer the above answer fixed it thanks i just dont come here straight away i like to try and fix my errors myself.

Answer (score 1):

Add [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.tostring%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
 txtHypotenuse.Text = Math.Sqrt(SumOfSquares(Side1 , Side2)).ToString();
```